# Issue while migrating data into specific existing PostgreSQL schema using AWS DMS from oracle

Tags: postgresql, aws-dms

I am trying to migrate oracle data into PostgreSQL database(dev1)/schema (schema_53) using AWS DMS service. Target schema is already created with all objects so I only want to transfer data from oracle to PostgreSQL. However, when I am running migration task I can see a new schema created which is having same name as of source oracle schema , instead of populating data in existing postgres schema.

I have created endpoint by providing URL , port, username, password and DB name of PostgreSQL but I don't see any provision of providing schema name. It seems I am missing some concepts of postgresql.

Can someone please guide me on is it possible migrate data into existing specific schema of  PostgreSQL using AWS DMS, as I don't see any option while creating endpoint.

I have run below queries on postgresql DB:

```
>  ALTER SCHEMA schema_53 OWNER TO dev_53;
>  GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE dev1 to dev_53;
>  GRANT CREATE ON DATABASE dev1 TO dev_53;
>  GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA schema_53 TO dev_53;
>  GRANT UPDATE, INSERT, SELECT, DELETE, TRUNCATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_53 TO dev_53;

      ----------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to set `TargetSchema` in the task setting. You may try setting TargetSchema as the existing schema you are planning to use. Below is the snapshot of Task setting.

```
"TargetMetadata": {
        "ParallelApplyBufferSize": 0,
        "ParallelApplyQueuesPerThread": 0,
        "ParallelApplyThreads": 0,
        "TargetSchema": <Your Schema>,
        "InlineLobMaxSize": 0,
        "ParallelLoadQueuesPerThread": 0,
        "SupportLobs": true,
        "LobChunkSize": 0,
        "TaskRecoveryTableEnabled": false,
        "ParallelLoadThreads": 0,
        "LobMaxSize": 15,
        "BatchApplyEnabled": false,
        "FullLobMode": false,
        "LimitedSizeLobMode": true,
        "LoadMaxFileSize": 0,
        "ParallelLoadBufferSize": 0
    }
```

You may find additional details here. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TaskSettings.TargetMetadata.html